# want to remove item from list view and add to another listview

Tags: android, listview

It's removing from the **list** but adding according to the position.  So adding **duplicate items** in the **list**.

```
refreshedList.remove(new_position);
mg_mappingAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
mgBenData.add(mgBenData.get(new_position));
mg_mappingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mg_mappingAdapter2 = new MgMappingAdapter2(getActivity(), refreshedList);
mg_mappingAdapter = new MgMappingAdapter11(getActivity(),
    R.layout.mgnregauserlistlayout,mgBenData);
mListView.setAdapter(mg_mappingAdapter);
mappedListView.setAdapter(mg_mappingAdapter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
Object object = refreshedList.remove(new_position); // replace Object with Element type of List, ArrayList<Element>
mgBenData.add(object);
 mg_mappingAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
 mg_mappingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 mg_mappingAdapter2 = new MgMappingAdapter2(getActivity(), refreshedList);
 mg_mappingAdapter = new MgMappingAdapter11(getActivity(),
R.layout.mgnregauserlistlayout,mgBenData);
     mListView.setAdapter(mg_mappingAdapter);
     mappedListView.setAdapter(mg_mappingAdapter2);
```

Just add removed item in a list which is showing deleted item in a list.Hope it will help you.